# Notepad++ - Continue Search from top

Tags: search, notepad++, plugins

In general when we do a Find in Notepad++, it starts from the current cursor position and continues till the end of the document.

Due to this, to search a complete document, we have to go to the beginning or end of the document and use Find Up / Find Down.

Is there a way to continue the search again from the top of the document after reaching the end of the document. Any npp plugins that would get this work done?

Answer (score 87, accepted):

Make sure you have Wrap Around checked.

[image: Notepad++ Find Dialog]

Comment: This only works with the Find dialog itself, but not with the simple F3 "find next"  which is unfortunate

Comment: If the option is enable in "Find" dialog, it's also enable with the shortcut "find next" (F3)