# less: continue search from top

Tags: less

Is there an automatic way (through command line params for example) of keep searching from start of text when the end is reached?

*(same as [Notepad++ - Continue Search from top](https://superuser.com/questions/620552/notepad-continue-search-from-top) but with `less` linux command instead of Notepad++)*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't believe there is a way to do this automatically, but if you're doing incremental searches with just the single keystroke

```
n
```

anyway, then when you get to the end of the file just press

```
g
```

to go back to the top and continue searching incrementally with

```
n
```

Comment: Thats what I'm doing, but I was looking for an automatic way

Comment: According to man page, there isn't one. All you have is `\ ` and `?` and `n`and `N`